Compare entity to database records with CriteriaBuilder
Is there a way to query records by comparing them to the entity properties directly with CriteriaBuilder, or do I need to write the comparison manually for each property?
public static Specification<ModelEntity> byModel(ModelEntity modelFilter) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root, modelFilter);
}

I don't like writing the following:
public static Specification<ModelEntity> byModel(ModelEntity modelFilter) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.and(
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("attribute_1"), modelFilter.getAttribute_1()),
            criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("attribute_2"), modelFilter.getAttribute_2()),
            // ...
    );
}


Criteria api within the JPA spec does not have query by example functionality, but some JPA providers do ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/ORMQueries#:~:text=Query%20by%20example%20enables%20you%20to%20specify%20queries,instance%20and%20an%20optional%20query%20by%20example%20policy and others)
